# A thread that will keep running?

Tags: java, android

I am writing some Android code,
Here is the structure: (Pseudo)

```
public class AThread extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while(true){
      i++;
      System.out.println(i);
    }  
  }
}
```

Then I new a instance of AThread class and call the start() method.
My question is:
The int i doesn't seem to keep adding in the while loop.
Why is the reason and how can I make the thread keep running the task
written in the while loop.

Because I am running some real-time analysis function...

Here is the actual one I wrote:

```
    int i = 0;
    running = true;
    while(running) {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);            
        if((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("analyzing");
            // read two lines per time.
            result = filter(lines, bufferedReader.readLine());
            if(!result[0].equals("emp")) {
                System.out.println("x: " + result[0] + " " + "y: " + result[1]);
                System.out.println(MainActivity.analysisKeyPress.classify(Integer.valueOf(result[0]), Integer.valueOf(result[1]), "0"));
                System.out.println("insert into db..");
                MainActivity.dbhelper.addKeyLog(getCurrentRunningService(), result[0], result[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems that the `int i` won't increase till there are several lines for `BufferedReader` to read.

Comment: Have you called `.start()` on your `Thread`?

Comment: Yes, I did call the .start() method

Comment: that code won't even compile.

Comment: That's was just a clean structure for quick understanding of my situation, sorry man. But I add the complete block for further inspecting

Comment: How do you expect it to loop if you have a `wait()` sentence just after the first iteration?

Comment: @DavidXu It would by nice if you'd explain **why** it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Niek Haarman because it is missing the ; after i++

Comment: i++ without a semicolon?

Comment: @nKn Hey, Sorry that was when I was debugging.
It can't keep running even I throw wait() away.

Comment: @DavidXu Of course. But it is obvious that the poster does not mean this. He obviously made a typo simplifying the code (which is normally a good thing, simplifying! However, in this cade I think he actually simplified it a bit too much). What I meant, is that such a comment is useless.

Comment: @NiekHaarman Thanks for your comment, so I'd add all the block, so people can do further inspecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment out this part:

```
result = filter(lines, bufferedReader.readLine());
if(!result[0].equals("emp")) {
    System.out.println("x: " + result[0] + " " + "y: " + result[1]);
    System.out.println(MainActivity.analysisKeyPress.classify(Integer.valueOf(result[0]), Integer.valueOf(result[1]), "0"));
    System.out.println("insert into db..");
    MainActivity.dbhelper.addKeyLog(getCurrentRunningService(), result[0], result[1]);
}
```

the loop *will* work.

So obviously, some method in that part blocks your code. Try running a debugger and step-by-step execute the code to see where you code stops executing. That's why your loop doesn't continue.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it works now.
The input lines came from a process(Android) running below command:
(getevent -l /dev/input/event2). I will try to debug the block you mentioned, thank for a great support for now.

Answer (score 1):

After increasing and typing your index you have a `readLine` call which is a waiting action. Make sure that your `BufferedReader` object gets the line it expects to get.